# Using Regular Expression to capture text within font tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regular expression to capture the text in between the font field and store it as a javascript variable.

```
<TD class="example">
<font>
I need this information captured
</font>
</TD>
```

I found examples that show that this regular expression:

```
<b>(.*?)</b>
```

could work with this HTML:

```
blah <b>one</b> blah blah <b>two</b>YO!
```

so I dont understand why this:

```
<font>(.*?)</font>
```

would not work to find this:

```
<font>
I need this information captured
</font>
```

Comment: In what way does the font regex not work? Do you get weird results? No results?

Comment: `.` does not match newline by default. Try `[\s\S]` instead of `.`

Comment: why regex, when you can simply do with `document.getElementsByTagName('font')[0].innerText`?

Comment: I need to specifically find the text within TD class="example" > Font > "I need this information captured"

Answer (score 3):

`<font>(.*?)</font>` doesn't work because the dot can't match newlines, you must replace it with `[\s\S]`

```
<font>([\s\S]*?)</font>
```

note: in your code, don't forget to escape the slash

If you want to find the `<font>` tag that is a descendant of `<td class="example">`, you obtain a more complicated pattern, because you must ensure that you are always in the `<td>`:

```
<td class="example">(?:(?=([^<]+|<(?!\/td>|font)))\1)*<font>([\s\S]*?)<\/font>
```

This pattern works only if your `<td>` tag doesn't contain other `<td>` tags before the `<font>` tag.

pattern details:

This part describes allowed content before the `<font>` tag:

```
(?:                         # open a non capturing group
    (?=                     # open a lookahead
        (                   # open the capture group 1
            [^<]+           # all that is not a <
          |                 # OR
            <(?!\/td>|font) # a < not followed by /td> or font
        )                   # close capture group 1
    )                       # close the lookahead
    \1                      # backreference to capture group 1
)*                          # close the non capturing group
```

This is a trick to emulate an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>...)` *(feature that is not available in javascript)*. This is a group inside which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack. This feature is necessary here because a simple subpattern like `(?:[^<]+|<(?!\/td>|font))*` may cause a [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

The trick use the fact that the content of a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is naturaly atomic. The content is described inside a capturing group inside the lookahead, and you put a backreference to the capturing group after the closing parenthesis of the lookahead. `\1` refers to a capture that is fixed once and for all, you can repeat it with no problems.

Comment: The font tags happen multiple times in my document so how would I specifically target the font tag that falls under the td class="example"?

Comment: @user3199597: the simple regex way is to find the content of `<td class="example">` with a first pattern and then searching for `<font>` tags. But if you have the possibility to use the DOM to do this, use it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for regex, but regex is not an appropriate tool for parsing HTML.
jQuery would make querying for that very simple.

```
$("TD.example > font").text()
```

Comment: This would be a way better solution, can you provide any documentation to point in the direction of this?